# netcat, nc, listen to several requests

Tags: networking, debug, netcat

I am trying to debug a network client. I just need to see several HTTP requests made in sequence.

my first idea was o run `nc -l 80`, but it will keep open the socket after the first connection. Is there a way to run it quickly as a deamon or multithreaded mode? without having to setup inetd or the likes?

my inelegant solution so far is:

`while true; do echo 123 | sudo nc -l 80; done`

it works but is a pain to kill :)

Also you can see there that i do not care at all what is replied to the client. I just want to see the requests coming in without having to install apache/ngix/any more complex script than `nc`

Comment: Why not use a packet sniffer like Wireshark?

Comment: mostly because every host nowadays have `nc` by default. So i want to learn something that i can use anytime without any overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to do:

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

which will return proper HTTP responses to the requests also.